# Android button height is different

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have two buttons inside a linear layout which have same properties defined. But to my surprise, both have different height. Please see the xml code below

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/default_people_thumb" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUploadHeader"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.Small.Bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/choose_a_profile_photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.ExtraSmall.Bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/photo_upload_initial" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChoosePhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/choose_photo_from_gallery" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/choose_photo_from_gallery" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Button image goes like this]

Can you please help me to have the same height. I am wondering as to how both behaves differently. Also added includeFontPadding for the button. But no hope :(.

Comment: there may problem with your drawables... try to check it out first

Comment: Can you share `drawable/login_button_selector`?

Comment: Even if i use the same button selector for both buttons, the problem still persists

Comment: use same padding properties in both files...

Comment: can you post code of your drawable and string.xml?

Comment: @Vyshnavi If your both buttons are in Linear layout then apply weight for both buttons. Also Change your linearlayout height wrap_content to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your background drawables have different padding or height. check `@drawable/btn_large_gray` and `@drawable/login_button_selector`

Answer (score 0):

put both the button inside linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/default_people_thumb" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUploadHeader"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.Small.Bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/choose_a_profile_photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.ExtraSmall.Bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/photo_upload_initial" />


            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChoosePhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/choose_photo_from_gallery" />
               </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_large_gray"
                android:text="@string/skip" />
           </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and adjust both linear layouts as you like it

Comment: Not working man. Also please don't insist adding more linear layouts as this may induce more time to draw the layout by android

Comment: ok forget the layouts...have you tried fixing the height of the button like android:layout_height=5dp?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough space on the bottom for the last button? If there is not enough space for it, the button will be automatically cropped to fit the screen. To avoid this you could put the entire LinerLayout inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining property `android:layout_weight` for each element in your `LinearLayout`, so they can have the same height.

For example :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/default_people_thumb" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUploadHeader"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.Small.Bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/choose_a_profile_photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                style="@style/Text.Quaternary.ExtraSmall.Bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/photo_upload_initial" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChoosePhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/choose_photo_from_gallery" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/choose_photo_from_gallery" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The idea is to give as much space to each element. Your `LinearLayout` contains different elements so by choosing `wrap_content` in the `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width`, space available  will be allocated for each element added. And as you `TextView`s and `Button`s are not the same...

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

You are using different style for both the buttons,
i.e. "@style/Text.Quaternary.Small.Bold" and "@style/Text.Quaternary.ExtraSmall.Bold" you should use only one style for both buttons